# .htaccess - Exclude subdomain from domain password protection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I'm pretty bad configuring `.htaccess` files and I need some help with my domain and subdomain access configuration. I have an htaccess file to require user access to my domain into the web root folder:

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
AuthName "Developers Only"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

The problem is that it requires an authentication for my subdomain which I don't want it protected, because it is for public access. How can achieve that?

My web root directory is at `/home/user/public_html/web` and my subdomain root directory is at `/home/user/public_ftp/sites`

Also, I have a redirection in the htaccess file for the main domain to force users accessing with `www` and I don't know if it does conflict. Here is the redirection:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I'm working with Symfony2 for PHP, so this is needed.

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me(Just set allowed referers and the rest will be denied):

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://example.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www.example.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://subdomain.example.com/" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://subdomain.example.com$" locally_linked=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" locally_linked=1
```

After this you can do the :

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=locally_linked
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will test it, because I used something different working with apache auth + symfony user auth, so it worked... pretty well, with one inconvenient. My users could access to our platform, but they don't know that. Anyway, I will take it for the future and mark it as answer if working ^^ I really appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SetEnvIf host ^sub\.domain\.com$ noauth=1

#auth
AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
AuthName "Developers Only"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

 #Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

Replace **sub.domain.com** with your subdomain that you dont want to password protect.

Comment: I've tried and still not working. As I read Googling this issue, this works when your Request was made from that subdomain into the domain to ignore authentication, but not to allow access from outside into the subdomain ignoring authentication. Anyway, thanks ^^ all help is appreciated